# Setting DateTimePicker.Value throws "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I have a `DateTimePicker` named `dtpCommitDate`. I am assigning its `Value` property like this:

```
dtpCommitDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
```

This throws a runtime exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't think that's where your exception is coming from, there are no strings in that piece of code.

Comment: Using the exact same code above I can't reproduce the error. Are you running the debugger? Do you see your code fail on exactly this line? It seems unlikely to me.

Comment: What does your DateTimePicker.Value setter look like?

Comment: @AaronPalmer `DateTimePicker` is a Microsoft control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps he is overriding `Value`.  That is the only thing I can think of that might throw that error.

Comment: format of this control(dtpCommitDate) is to custom, is any issue with this..

Comment: Have you set the `CustomFormat` property? Is the format string correct? If so, please provide

Comment: I have set the format  dtpCommitDate.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date);dtpCommitDate.CustomFormat = "'MM/DD/YYYY'";

Comment: Yes i have set the property to custom..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a single quote in the date format string and being all upper case will not give the desired result.

Try

```
dtpCommitDate.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Although, I never received the same error you have, is the exception being thrown on either the date assignment, or the format assignment, or is it somewhere else in the code as per @Patrick Quirk's comment above.